# Convert named parameters to unnamed in prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have an SQL query that uses named placeholders, and an associative array containing corresponding keys and values.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (:a, :b, :c)
```

```
[
  'a' => 'ValueA',
  'c' => 'ValueC',
  'b' => 'ValueB'
]
```

Now I need to convert the query - and the corresponding parameters - to use unnamed (question marks) instead.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

```
[
  0 => 'ValueA',
  1 => 'ValueB',
  2 => 'ValueC'
]
```

How can I do this, without risking that the parameters end up in the wrong order?

Comment: Outside of "make sure you pass them in the right order", what kind of answer were you hoping for? Are you considering a large scale change where you would programatically edit all your queries like this?

Comment: I have a need to store SQL queries and parameters in a way that is compatible with other systems (which don't support named placeholders). But I still want to use named placeholders in code, for readability and minimizing the risk of accidentally providing parameters in the wrong order. Unfortunately, not all systems support them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make use of `preg_replace_callback` and simply append the value of the corresponding parameter to the new array:

```
/**
 * @return mixed[] An array containing two elements: the modified SQL query (string), 
 *                 and the modified params (array).
 */
function unnameSqlParameters(string $sql, array $params): array
{
    $newParams = [];

    $newSql = preg_replace_callback(
        '/:(\w+)/',
        static function (array $matches) use ($params, &$newParams): string {
            $name = $matches[1];

            if (!array_key_exists($name, $params)) {
                throw new \RuntimeException("Cannot find parameter value for :{$name}.");
            }

            $newParams[] = $params[$name];

            return '?';
        },
        $sql
    );

    return [$newSql, $newParams];
}
```

Usage:

```
[$sql, $params] = unnameSqlParameters(
    'INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) VALUES (:a, :b, :c)',
    ['a' => 'ValueA', 'c' => 'ValueC', 'b' => 'ValueB']
);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/TTJVg)

Note that the used regex, as it is, will also match parameters (things like `:a`) inside strings. There are ways to prevent that if needed.

Comment: Great! I like this more than my proposed solution, since it is easier to understand and accomplishes the same task in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following function, which takes into account

- partially matching placeholder names, i.e. `:b` and `:bar`
- parameters appearing in different order in SQL vs. parameter array

```
function sqlNamedPlaceholdersToUnnamed(string &$sql, array &$params){
    // Sort params based on the order their keys appear in $sql
    $newParams = [];
    foreach($params as $key => $value){
        $result = preg_match("/:{$key}[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", $sql, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        if( $result !== 1 ) throw new \Exception("Unexpected result from preg_match. Expected 1, but got $result");
        $newParams[(int) $matches[0][1]] = $value;
    }
    ksort($newParams, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $newParams = array_values($newParams);


    // Replace named parameters with ? in $sql
    $newSql = preg_replace("/:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/", '?', $sql, -1, $count);
    if( $newSql === null ) throw new \Exception('Error when executing preg_replace');
    if( $count !== count($params) ) throw new \Exception("Number of placeholders not same as number of params");


    // Replace arguments with results
    $sql = $newSql;
    $params = $newParams;
}
```